# jQuery Datatable serverside reload with new post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have common function for all the server-side data-tables which accepts the table object, url and the post data. The post data consists of the values from the select boxes that are in the filter area.

```
UTIL.serverDatatable = function (table, api, data) {
        var token = "Bearer " + JSON.parse(UTIL.getItemLocalStorage('token'));
        return table.DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "paging": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: api,
                type: "post",
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
                },
                "data": data
            }
        });
    };
```

And another function to reload the datatable

```
UTIL.datatableReload = function(table) {
    table.ajax.reload();
};
```

This worked fine before these functions were made common. The post data was  changing when the filters changes and the reload function was called after that. But now when the data is changed, the post is not getting updated. Is there any solution for this? How to post the changed data via the ajax call?

Comment: i don't think it will work like this, i think you cannot make a common function for multiple datatable

Comment: This works fine except for the data part.

Comment: Can you add a snippet to simulate the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code as below

```
UTIL.serverDatatable = function (table, api, callback) {
    var token = "Bearer " + JSON.parse(UTIL.getItemLocalStorage('token'));
    return table.DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: api,
            type: "post",
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
            },
            "data": callback
        }
    });
};
```

Then call the util function as below

```
UTIL.serverDatatable(tablename, apiname, function(data){
   data.key= $('#input1').val();
});
```

And then call the function as

```
UTIL.datatableReload = function(table) {
    table.ajax.reload();
};
```